# Android Security application signing

Tags: android

If I upload a signed apk to appmarket  is it possible to any other developer to download the apk  and through  reverse eng  change the app  behavior and upload it with same name and different sign. If it is possible is  there any method to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

> If I upload a signed apk to appmarket is it possible to any other developer to download the apk and through reverse eng change the app behavior and upload it with same name and different sign.

If by "same name" you mean "same package", no. A package can only be updated through the same Google account that created its Play Store entry, and the package must be signed by the same signing key.

If by "same name" you mean "same title or display name that a user sees", then yes.

> If it is possible is there any method to stop it.

Do not distribute your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your app from this case by:

- Set some code for checking App's name, package's name in your source. If you detect any change -> stop the app.
- Obfuscate your source to hide the checking code. You can use Proguard (default Obfuscator) or [Bg+ Anti Decompiler/Obfuscator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgplus.Anti.JavaDecompiler) (a new & powerful Obfuscator)